# Can't push objects into array because it's undefined Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, es6-class

I am trying to push an object of type Card into an array and I am getting:
Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.
Here is the class Card:

```
class Card {
    
    constructor(value, suit) {
        this.Value = value;
        this.Suit = suit;
        this.Viewed = false;
    }
}
```

And Here is the class Game:<br/ >

```
class Game{
    construct(){
        this.GroundCards = []; //This is the array i am trying to push objects at.
        this.GroundCard = null;
        this.NbCardsPickedSeven = 0;
    }

    pushCard(card){
        console.log(this.GroundCards);
        this.GroundCards.push(card);
    }
}
```

When I do `console.log(this.GroundCards);` It's printing undefined into the console, and then it's giving me an error.
Can someone tell me why is the GroundCards attribute undefined in the first place?
I also tried initializing it in the constructor like:
`this.GroundCards = new Array();` and it still didn't work.
I am still new to Javascript syntax a bit, so sorry for any obvious mistakes.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: How are you calling your `pushCard` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor is named `construct` - it is therefore never called. It should be called `constructor`.

Comment: man I feel so stupid, I missed it, it's a shame visual studio code didn't actually point it out for me.......Thank you verymuch

Comment: Good call. However, questions caused by typographical errors should be closed as such because they are very unlikely to helpful to future visitors.

Comment: @KamelYehya `construct()` is a perfectly valid method, just like `pushCard()` is. VS Code doesn't know that you meant `constructor`.